# Save the value as a sring

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose an $amount = 1459 I need to insert into mysql through php and the output has to stay in mysql table like that ["1459 "] .
I tried wiyth this.But it doesn't work.

```
["$amount "]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding "" to the value doesn't make it a string.You have to concatenate the value as follows in order to make it a string.

```
$amount = '1459 ';
$insert = '["'.amount .'"]';
```

After this use $insert in the insert statement and the value inserted in your database will be as ["1459 "].

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you so much dude.You made my day.

Comment: Glad i could help...Accepting the answer would be highly appreciated since it will help to increase my reputation points.

Comment: Yeah sure.I will